# Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:9.0.0

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, gcmlistenerservice

I am trying to get 'FCM' and 'GcmListenerService' working, i added the required dependencies to gradle files as shown below.
but when i tried to build the project, i received the below posted errors..

please let mek know how to fix it

**build.gradle app**:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile project(':appcompat')
compile project(':securepreferences')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0' // .0.1

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'

compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.4'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7' 

compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'

compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0' 
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0' // 7.5' 

compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.8.0'
compile files('app/libs/android-viewbadger.jar')
compile files('app/libs/iDappsImagesLib_v0.2.jar')
compile files('app/libs/iDappsToolsLib_v0.1.jar')
compile files('gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar')
```

}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

**build.grdle proj**:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.7' // 1.8?
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:9.0.0'
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
}
```

**error**:

```
Error:Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:9.0.0.
Searched in the following locations:
file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gms/google-services/9.0.0/google-services-9.0.0.pom
file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gms/google-services/9.0.0/google-services-9.0.0.jar
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/9.0.0/google-services-9.0.0.pom
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/9.0.0/google-services-9.0.0.jar
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/9.0.0/google-services-9.0.0.pom
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/9.0.0/google-services-9.0.0.jar
Required by:
project :
```

Comment: have you updated the Google repository to the latest version in the SDK manager?

Answer (score 1):

The last `google-services` version is `3.1.0`, so edit your **build.gradle project** file as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        ...
    }
}
```

Then, in your **build.gradle app** file, you can use `com.google.gms:google-services:9.0.0`, but I think, actually the last version is `11.0.2`, so I will recommend you to update

Answer (score 0):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#manually_add_firebase

Your app/build.gradle's dependencies looks fine, but make sure you have `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the root-bottom.

Your project/build.gradle does not. From docs:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}
```

Why do you have an extra `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:9.0.0'` in there?

Please review and double check your setup against the docs.